# Can I refer to the iterated $_ value in an outer loop from the inner loop?

Tags: powershell

For demo purposes I have a JSON document that lists continents and some countries in each continent:

```powershell
$json = ConvertFrom-Json '[{"Continent" : "Europe","Countries" : ["UK","France","Germany"]},
                           {"Continent" : "Africa","Countries" : ["Mali","Malawi","Nigeria"]}]'
```

If I want to get a list of all the countries therein I can do it in one line of PowerShell by piping to the `foreach` cmdlet twice:

```powershell
$json | foreach {$_.Countries} | foreach {$_ | Select @{Name="Country";Expression={$_}}}
```

```
Country                                                               
------- UK                                                                     France                                                                 Germany                                                                Mali                                                                   Malawi                                                                 Nigeria
```

All quite normal. However, if I want to Select each Country's continent too then I need a multi-statement script block:

```powershell
$json | foreach {
    $Continent = $_.Continent
    $_.Countries | foreach {
                            $_ | Select-Object @{Name="Continent";Expression={$Continent}},@{Name="Country";Expression={$_}}
                           }
}
```

```
Continent     Country
---------     ------- 
Europe        UK      
Europe        France  
Europe        Germany 
Africa        Mali    
Africa        Malawi  
Africa        Nigeria
```

I love the terseness of PowerShell so in this second example I'm slightly deflated about the fact that that I need to store the iterated continent in a variable. All I'm wondering is, can I make this better? Can I make it terser? Is there a way of referring to the iterated value in the outer loop from within the call to `Select-Object`?

That's all, basically just trying to learn more about PowerShell and what it can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the value of the outer `$_` directly, but you can capture its value using [`param`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj554301.aspx):

```powershell
param($x=$_)
```

This will allow you to technically have everything on one line:

```powershell
$json | foreach { param($x=$_) $_.Countries | foreach { $_ | Select-Object @{Name="Continent";Expression={$x.Continent}},@{Name="Country";Expression={$_}}}}
```

You can also reduce the size of your code by using some standard aliases (namely, `%` for `foreach` and `select` for `Select-Object`):

```powershell
$json | % { param($x=$_) $_.Countries | % { $_ | select @{Name="Continent";Expression={$x.Continent}},@{Name="Country";Expression={$_}}}}
```

But I would only recomment doing this for quick runs in the console.  Putting code that packed and unreabale into production is just plain evil. ;)

Comment: Thanks @iCodez. Param is interesting, I didn't realise you could do that in a script block. So there you go, I came here to learn something new about PowerShell, and I did just that. Thank you.  I certainly agree that using % (other than in your own console where no-one is going to see it) is evil. My aim here is not to reduce the number of characters I'm typing, rather the number of tokens in my code, and there's a subtle difference there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to get that "outer" `$_`. Moreover, even if you could, I don't think it's a good idea.

You can refer to parent scopes (recursively) in Powershell using `Get-Variable -Scope 1` where 1 is the immediate parent, but that doesn't seem to work in nested `ForEach-Object` calls. See [about_Scopes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) for more information on that.

In general though it's better to code for readability, in my opinion.

If your primary reason for being bothered by a multi-statement block is having it on more than one line, you can separate your statements with a `;` to keep them on the same line.

```powershell
$json | foreach { $Continent = $_.Continent ; $_.Countries | foreach { $_ | Select-Object @{Name="Continent";Expression={$Continent}},@{Name="Country";Expression={$_}} }}
```

Personally, I prefer it broken up.

Comment: Thanks @briantist, I guess that confirms my original thinking.